# How to remove multiple Circle for google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to remove all the 4 circle from google map with a click of a button, but currently I can only remove one circle. Could anyone let me know how I can remove the multiple circle at once with a click of a button. Sorry I am new to this. Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
   <input onclick="removecircle();" type=button value="Remove line">
    <input onclick="addcircle();" type=button value="Restore line">

<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    var cityCircle;

  var citymap = {
    chicago: {
      center: {lat: 41.878, lng: -87.629},
      population: 2714856
    },
    newyork: {
      center: {lat: 40.714, lng: -74.005},
      population: 8405837
    },
    losangeles: {
      center: {lat: 34.052, lng: -118.243},
      population: 3857799
    },
    vancouver: {
      center: {lat: 49.25, lng: -123.1},
      population: 603502
    }
  };

  function initMap() {
    // Create the map.
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: {lat: 37.090, lng: -95.712},
      mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    });

    // Construct the circle for each value in citymap.
    // Note: We scale the area of the circle based on the population.
    for (var city in citymap) {
      // Add the circle for this city to the map.
       cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map,
        center: citymap[city].center,
        radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[city].population) * 100
      });
    }
  }

     function addcircle(){

        cityCircle.setMap(map);
        }

        function removecircle(){

        cityCircle.setMap(null);
        }
```

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFynJ.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T944k.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep references to the circles (and the map) in the global scope (where they will be accessible from HTML click listener functions).  Then process through all the circles to either add or remove them from the map.

```
var circles = [];
var map;

function initMap() {
  // Create the map.
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: {
      lat: 37.090,
      lng: -95.712
    },
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });

  // Construct the circle for each value in citymap.
  // Note: We scale the area of the circle based on the population.
  for (var city in citymap) {
    // Add the circle for this city to the map.
    var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
      center: citymap[city].center,
      radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[city].population) * 100
    });
    // keep reference to the circle
    circles.push(cityCircle);
  }
}

function addcircle() {
  for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
    circles[i].setMap(map);
  }
}

function removecircle() {
  for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
    circles[i].setMap(null);
  }
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/n3zf21c5/1/)

**code snippet:**

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input onclick="removecircle();" type=button value="Remove circles">
<input onclick="addcircle();" type=button value="Restore circles">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  var circles = [];
  var map;

  function initMap() {
    // Create the map.
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 3,
      center: {
        lat: 37.090,
        lng: -95.712
      },
      mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    });

    // Construct the circle for each value in citymap.
    // Note: We scale the area of the circle based on the population.
    for (var city in citymap) {
      // Add the circle for this city to the map.
      var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map,
        center: citymap[city].center,
        radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[city].population) * 100
      });
      circles.push(cityCircle);
    }
  }

  function addcircle() {
    for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
      circles[i].setMap(map);
    }
  }

  function removecircle() {
    for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
      circles[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
    var cityCircle;

  var citymap = {
    chicago: {
      center: {
        lat: 41.878,
        lng: -87.629
      },
      population: 2714856
    },
    newyork: {
      center: {
        lat: 40.714,
        lng: -74.005
      },
      population: 8405837
    },
    losangeles: {
      center: {
        lat: 34.052,
        lng: -118.243
      },
      population: 3857799
    },
    vancouver: {
      center: {
        lat: 49.25,
        lng: -123.1
      },
      population: 603502
    }
  };
</script>
```